# Recover Outlook Express email account passwords

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-express, password-recovery

After restoring Outlook Express account settings from a second drive, I used to input the password manually in *Incoming Mail Server*'s password field (account settings).

Now I forgot this password. How can I retrieve this password?

Comment: what operating system?  what would help...

Comment: to backup/restore your emailaccount settings from Windows http://superuser.com/questions/135128/restoring-outlook-express-passwords-and-settings-from-a-second-drive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nirsoft's website](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html) has some [free password recovery tools](http://www.nirsoft.net/password_recovery_tools.html). Try to download and running one of them. You specifically need *Mail Password Recovery*.

I hope this helps :)

---

The author is not responsible for any damage or loss caused
by using the programs.

Answer (score 2):

This password comes from the provider of you e-mail account, typically your internet service provider.